# HTML form in for loop posts only first data with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $name = 'name' . $i;
        $id = 'id' . $i;
        echo '<form method="POST" action="" name = "' . $name . '" id = "' . $id . '">';
        echo'<input type="number" name="roll" id="roll" placeholder="Enter Roll"><br>' .
        '<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"><br>' .
        '<input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address"><br>' .
        '<button type="button" onclick="submitdata(this);"> Submit </button><br>';
        echo '</form><br>';
    }
?>
```

This is the php code. I insert the form in the php echo tag. I use mysql database.

```
function submitdata() {
    var roll = document.getElementById("roll").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'roll=' + roll + '&name=' + name + '&address=' + address;
    if (roll == '' || name == '' || address == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        // AJAX code to submit form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is my JavaScript code. Please help me by suggestion. How can I insert form data from php loop?

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Any `id` must be unique in single document.

Comment: Dear @Alive to Die, Thanks a lot. But I am still not understanding because, the code you wrote does not insert any data to mysql database. Only database connected. Can you indicate error in these file- index.php https://pastebin.com/LLUFWJEe    and submit.php   https://pastebin.com/jwqphVkZ   . Thank you again.

Comment: You are using five forms, so submitting the first form will submit only the data in first form.